# Got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when running Elastic Beanstalk CLI

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, file-not-found, ebcli

I've been using the [Elastic Beanstalk CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) for a couple weeks, but all of a sudden I got the following error message when running `eb create`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/elias/.ebcli-virtual-env/executables/eb", line 45, in <module>
    exit(_exec_cmd(['/Users/elias/.ebcli-virtual-env/bin/eb'] + sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/Users/elias/.ebcli-virtual-env/executables/eb", line 25, in _exec_cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "/Users/elias/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/elias/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1847, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/elias/.ebcli-virtual-env/bin/eb
```

How do I fix this? Note that I am using the CLI on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by just uninstalling and reinstalling the Elastic Beanstalk CLI.

To uninstall on macOS, just run `rm -r ~/.ebcli-virtual-env`.
To reinstall on macOS, follow the [official Quick Start instructions](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#2-quick-start).